# Folder Redirection won't load on Windows 7 Machine in Windows 2008 R2 Network

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, folder-redirection

Okay so redirected profiles don't load exactly, but the computer is joined to the network and it won't display any of the users files on their desktop that are in their redirected profile.  I know this because we have a Terminal Server and when the user logs in there, her files appear.

I checked the users' profile in `Active Directory Users and Computers` and compared it with a working users profile.  When that didn't turn up any differences, I looked at her computer and found that on the `Dial-in` tab the `Network Access Permission` wasn't set to `Control access through NPS Network Policy` like it was on the other machines on the network; so I selected it, ran `gpupdate /force` on her machine and rebooted.  This did not fix the issue.

Is there anything else that could be preventing the redirected files on the users desktop from showing up when the user logs in?

Comment: Look through the logs of the computer that the user logs in to when her profile won't load.  It will tell you why.  We are talking about Roaming Profiles and not Folder Redirection here right?

Comment: Wrong we're talking about Folder Redirection (that doesn't work).  The paths should point to `\\data\redirect`

Comment: Ok, well you'll probably want to edit your question (or I can) to reflect that as they are two different functions and there is a big enough difference between the two that it will affect any advice/answers I give to you.  Look in the event viewer of the computer having trouble getting her FR folders.  Specifically look for 502 events.

Answer (score 0):

The user must have ownership of the redirected folder on the server side (Security -> Advanced -> Ownership).  It is not enough to simply give them full control permissions to it.

Comment: Tried this...maybe it was part of the problem as she was not added as a user with permissions to her profile folder, but there are other errors which are not 502s I'll post them above.